# Scrolling background with CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to get a background that can scroll up/down to allow for the image to be viewed. The code seems right, but it doesn't allow me to scroll. Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--CSS init-->
    <style>
        html {
            background-image: url("../Pictures/example_bg.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this really your entire HTML document...?

Comment: if this is it, there is nothing to scroll

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I did. I opened it to make sure the image looked right and learned the scrolling didn't work. The image is 1920x4320, so it doesn't fit on the screen. Does scroll not allow you to move the image up and down?

Comment: Get yourself a book on HTML programming. I'd recommend HEADFIRST. This is completely the wrong way to do things and you'll be banging your head against a wall until you know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-attachment: scroll;` means that the background will follow the page when it scrolls. It's the default, so you don't have to specify it.

You can't scroll to see the entire image because you don't have any content in your `body` element (and no `body` element at all), so the page is only a few pixels high (the default margin/padding). Put an element in the `body` element and specify a height for it that is as high as the background image, and you will be able to scroll.

You should have a `head` element also, that's where the style goes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html {
            background-image: url("../Pictures/example_bg.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: scroll;
        }
        div {
            height: 4320px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to scroll around an image, simply place it in an IMG element. You don't need to place it on the background unless you intend to place things over it.

Also, your HTML is never going to work as you've written it. I'd recommend getting a decent book and working through it. HEADFIRST HTML is great for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

you can also write for the background-position:fixed;
and also make the body very big height just for test that you will be able to see the scroll.